# Recursive function to print numbers counting down in c

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am tyring to write a program that reads an integer n from the keyboard, and prints n, n-1, ... n, using a recursive function. The code below works, but I don't completely understand why or the steps involving the recursive function. Could someone please explain?

```
void countingdown(int n){
    if (n == 1){
        printf("%d\n", n);
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        countingdown(n - 1);
        return;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    countingdown(n);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps this answer about tail recursion would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010/1212725

Comment: It would probably help you to understand if you ran the program in a debugger. With such a tool you can run the program step by step and inspect the values of all variables in every step.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the recursive function `countdown()`

**Similar to this**

```
int countingdown(int n){

    if (n == 0){//return exit from recursion
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        countingdown(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Suppose we call it with `countdown(5)`.
Until we reach to `0` printing n, i.e 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 will continue. In last step that variable n reach to 0 as we express in if section function returns and its execution ends.

***[Edit]***

Better one

```
void countingdown(unsigned int n){

    if (n){
        printf("%d\n", n);
        countingdown(n - 1);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Because this is an int function, should i not return an int?

Comment: For this situation no. its works. but  you can use `return 0` to be precise.

Comment: @user20102000 or simply just change from `int` --> `void` this function no need to return anything.

Comment: @user20102000 I provide a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, the user enters the value 3, then the following will happen:

1. The function `main` will call `countingdown` with the parameter `3`.
2. The function `countingdown` will then compare this parameter `3` with the value `1`, and, since that comparison evaluates to **false**, it will print the number `3` and then call `countingdown` (i.e. the function will call itself) with the parameter `2`.
3. This second instance of `countingdown` will now compare this parameter `2` with the value `1`, and, since that comparison evaluates to **false**, it will print the number `2` and call `countingdown` with the parameter `1`.
4. This third instance of `countingdown` will now compare the parameter `1` with the value `1`, and since that comparison now evaluates to **true**, it will print the number `1` and will not call itself again.

The recursive function treats the parameter `1` as special, since that is the value at which it should abort. When it encounters this value, it will stop calling itself recursively. If the function did not check for this special value, it would continue counting down forever and would also print `0`, `-1`, `-2`, etc.